# How to install Java SE 7 for testing on Mac that requires 6 for production?

Tags: java, installation

I have a development Mac computer which has Java 6 installed.  My development work done in Eclipse uses that.  For my personal own study and experiment, I'd like to use Java 7.  How should I install Java 7 so it does not interfere my normal work?

EDIT: my development work done on the computer actually is sometimes in Eclipse sometimes from command line or even in a different IDE. So ideally I want the environment for these other possibilities also intact.

Comment: Do you ever use the command line? If so, Java 7 will change the command line tools version.

Comment: You can specify a JRE in Eclipse for each project.  But you're probably going to have to mess around with whatever the Mac version of a path is, to make sure you're pointing to the correct JRE outside of Eclipse.

Comment: @Andrew, "have to mess around with whatever the Mac version of a path" is exactly what I'm the most unsure about and need the others' help and clarification on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install Java 7 from the installer package. Java will change the command line tools to Java 7, but Eclipse will continue to use Java 6. You can then use the command line tools for testing, or select Java 7 for an Eclipse project.

Comment: I forgot to mention, ideally I want my command-line java and javac to also be intact.  Any clean way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes. Find all the java command line utilities in `/usr/bin` and copy the files somewhere else before installing. Then after installing, copy them back.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this helps...

this is on eclipse tool bar,
eclipse > preferences

search for "installed" select the Installed JRE's option to see if yours is there.

search for "execution" select execution environments, select 1.6 and 1.7 and check that the setting are what you want.

you should also check the project setting and make sure to check which JRE they are using i.e workspace vs project settings.

Comment: Where to exactly check the project setting?

Comment: i dont have it open right now, but it should be, right click on the project, and select properties. ill update when i open it.

Comment: right click > properties > java compiler = project and workspace specific settings